# Issue with Informix (ifx_connect)

Tags: centos, informix

Hi I have a problem after installed informix client sdk (Ref : http://www.debian-administration.org/article/651/Connect_to_Informix_using_PHP5_on_Lenny_x86_64)

OS : CentOS

Here is the .php file that i use to connect

$db_conn = ifx_connect("dbname@IPHost","user","pass");

There is some error here,
Warning: ifx_connect() [function.ifx-connect]: E [SQLSTATE=IX 001 SQLCODE=-1829] in /var/www/html/index.php on line 5

is anyone know the solution ?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The way you find more about errors from Informix is often:

```
$ finderr -1829
-1829   Cannot open file citoxmsg.pam.

The file citoxmsg.pam is missing from the directory $INFORMIXDIR/msg.

If this error occurs, note all circumstances and contact IBM Technical Support.
$
```

(Give or take some blank lines.)  The `finderr` command is found in $INFORMIXDIR/bin.  You need $INFORMIXDIR set in the environment unless `/usr/informix` is correct - it could be a symlink to the actual software directory.

There are two possibilities:

1. You have not got INFORMIXDIR set in the environment when PHP is run, and/or the php.ini file does not define a value for $INFORMIXDIR, or the value is set incorrectly, or a default (quite possibly `/usr/informix`) is being used but the software is not installed there.
2. The installation is not complete - the relevant message file is missing as noted.

Of the two, I think reason 1 is much the more likely.

The IX001 value for SQLSTATE is of minimal use - it is the generic 'something went wrong with Informix' message.  The SQLCODE is much more significant and helpful.